# Limit post type to 1 per user

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, user-roles, the-events-calendar

I am using the events calendar pro, for my organization I need to limit the number of organizer profiles per Wordpress Account to 1.
I tried the following way in the functions file to limit user from creating additional organizer profiles. However I am still able to make new users with the role "OV_LID":

```
    function limit_organizers_per_account($user_id, $new_role) {
    if ($new_role === 'ov_lid') { // Adjust the role slug if necessary
        $organizers_count = 0;

        // Query the database to count the number of organizer profiles for the user
        $organizers_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_organizer', // Adjust the post type if necessary
            'author' => $user_id,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ));

        $organizers_count = $organizers_query->found_posts;

        if ($organizers_count > 1) {
            // User already has an organizer profile, remove the OV_LID role
            $user = new WP_User($user_id);
            $user->remove_role('OV_LID'); // Adjust the role slug if necessary

            // Display an error message
            $error_message = 'You are only allowed to have one organizer profile.';
            $user->add_error('organizer_error', $error_message);
        }
    }
}
add_action('set_user_role', 'limit_organizers_per_account', 10, 2);
```

Comment: This could be as simple as case sensitivity, as in some uses there's `ov_lid` and in others `OV_LID`. Double-check that first.